# New to Python- TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've looked into tuple through the forums in the site and none of the answers seem to match up with the same issue I am having. I am getting this error and I am not sure why. Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated! I am guessing my code is unnecessarily complicated?

```
import time
print "Welcome! I can tell you the year in which you will turn 100 years old!"
name = str(raw_input ('What is your name? '))
age = int(raw_input ('What is your age? '))
birthday = str(raw_input ('Has your birthday passed for the year? (answer yes or no) ')) 
curYear = time.localtime(time.time())

if birthday == str('y') or str('yes') or str('Yes'):
    bdayY = name + str(', ') + str('you will turn 100 years old in the year ') + (curYear + (int(100) - age)) + str('!')
    print bdayY
elif birthday == str('n') or str('no') or str('No'):
    bdayN = name + str(', ') + str('you will turn 100 years old in the year ') + (curYear + (int(100) - (age + int(1)))) + str('!')
    print bdayN
else:
    print "Invalid Answer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `str` on string literals isn't necessary.

`curYear` returns a time tuple which cannot be added to an `int`. You should have this instead:

```
curYear = time.localtime(time.time()).tm_year
#                                        ^
```

The `if` block is quite unreadable. Will be nice if you take a look at [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) in python 2:

```
bdayY = '%s, you will turn 100 years old in the year %s!'%(name, (curYear + 100 - age))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast everything into string except the year... when i tried your code, that's the only error i got.

If you write `str(curYear + (int(100) - age))` instead of `(curYear + (int(100) - age))` in both assignement it should be ok.

However, i would recommend that you do the calculations in separate variables. You are mixing concatenation and additions, making it really easy to make errors, and very hard to debug...